# Is there anything like memcached for Windows shares?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, cache

Our current infrastructure has an application running on an application server and mapping a network share to run. This effectively turns all file I/O into network traffic which in most cases is ok, but for some of our processes this causes a severe performance hit.

Is there anything out there would allow us to copy the contents of the network share locally and do our processing on it, but still allow us to be sure we're not out of sync with the data on the network share? i.e. any changes we make get reflected on the server and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you're looking for the "Offline Files" feature.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183315%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Or maybe "folder redirection,"

http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc732275.aspx

But if you're just looking for the ability to cache a generic network share, Offline Files would be the way to go.  You should probably provide more specific details if you desire or require assistance with a particular implementation, but those would be the Windows features you're looking for.  (Note that in Server 2008, you need to install/enable "Desktop Experience" before you can use Offline Files.)